# Python Multiline Match End of String

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I'm trying to match until I hit a pattern("this" ignoring any white spaces between start of line and pattern) or until the end of a string in a paragraph by using:

```
r'.*?(?=^[^\S\n]*this|$)'
```

This regex string works fine if my string is only one line($ matches an end of line). However I could not find the regex to match a end of string, so is there a clean way around this? The following is my code:

```
import re  
a_str="""\  
paragraph starts here  
another line
this line may or may not exist"""  
a_match = re.compile(r'.*?(?=^[^\S\n]*this|$)', re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL).match(a_str)
```

**EDIT**:

Expected output:

```
"paragraph starts here\nanother line"
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 3):

It's now possible to denote the very end of string in multi-line mode with '\Z'.

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems like removing the extra '|$' in the look ahead did the trick.
Look ahead also matches end of string apparently - I'm assuming

```
r'.*?(?=^[^\S\n]*this)'
```